# Missing HTML code/tags when downloading page with C++

Tags: javascript, c++, html, wininet

I've finally succeeded in downloading a webpage to disk using the wininet library. I'm currently using the following c++ code:

```
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <wininet.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <cstring>

    #define SIZE 128


    int main(int argc, char ** argv)

    {

    HINTERNET Initialize,Connection,File;
    DWORD dwBytes;

    char ch;
    Initialize = InternetOpen("HTTPGET",INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT,NULL,NULL,0);

    Connection = InternetConnect(Initialize,argv[1],INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT,
    NULL,NULL,INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP,0,0);


    File = HttpOpenRequest(Connection,NULL,"/index.html",NULL,NULL,NULL,0,0);
    if(HttpSendRequest(File,NULL,0,NULL,0))
    {
        std::ofstream webSource;
        webSource.open(strcat(argv[1], "__.html"));
        while(InternetReadFile(File,&ch,1,&dwBytes))
        {
            if(dwBytes != 1)break;
            webSource << ch;
        }
        webSource.close();
    }

    InternetCloseHandle(File);
    InternetCloseHandle(Connection);
    InternetCloseHandle(Initialize);

    return 0;
}
```

But this is the only thing I'm getting when I choose to download with www.rottentomatoes.com

```
<HEAD><TITLE>Flixster</TITLE>

<META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=index.jsp">

<!--

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=maintenance.html">

-->

</HEAD>



<BODY>

</body>

</html>
```

What's the problem here? I should be getting text, links, image frames, and about 150KB worth of HTML.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

That `<meta>` tag is intended to redirect the client (which normally would be a browser) to another URL.  Your code is not responding to that, so all you see is the initial page.

This:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=index.jsp">
```

tells the client that after a zero second delay the page "index.jsp" should be fetched. You might see what happens if you start with the URL

> http://www.rottentomatoes.com/index.jsp

Comment: Fine, I also get the same "webpage" I got with www.rottentomatoes.com.

But now, when trying to download the page I get nothing. How come? Any solution, advice?

Comment: I'm getting a 403 error when I do it. I suggest trying things with a tool like curl or wget while developing your own software.

Comment: It works fine for me:
hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(
        hConnect,
        L"GET",
        L"/index.jsp",
        L"HTTP/1.1",
        NULL,
        NULL,
        INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD | INTERNET_FLAG_EXISTING_CONNECT,
        0);

Comment: Could you please point out how to insert this statement in my code? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's an immediate redirect to index.jsp.